# Logrotate to ignore the most recent file

Tags: linux, bash, logrotate

I'm going to use logrotate to manage log files, however, I just want to rotate the log files older than 2 days (I don't want logrotate change the file name for the most recent 2 days logs). Is there any way to do this?

My current config is like this:

/tmp/test.* {
    missingok
    daily
    rotate 2
}

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is for programming questions and not general computing issues. Please review [What topics can I ask here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more details. Question may be appropriate for [Super User](http://superuser.com) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) but do check their help before posting.

Answer (score 1):

Per logrotate's man entry:

`minage *count*: Do not rotate logs which are less than <count> days old.`

https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/logrotate/logrotate.8.en.html